# Tooltip with toggle div click to open, and then click to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

I am working on a toggle div, with tooltip.

The problem is that my tooltip shows "Click to open", But, after opening the toggle, the tooltip then needs to show only "Click to close"

Anyone please help me to do this.

**[Here](http://webcodesky.com/toggle/tooltip.zip)** is Zip file of my project.

And [**Live Link**](http://webcodesky.com/toggle)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".latestnews").click(function(){
        $(".latestnews_toggle").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Please help me to do this. I need the tooltip should show message according with open close. When close show "Click to open " and when open it should show "Click to close"

Comment: please post your relevant code, not a zip file that could contain anything

Comment: I also attached live link. And believe me my zip file have only html file, nothing else.

Comment: There are thousands of questions here on SO that explain toggles and changing content. Please search.

Comment: "*And believe me my zip file have only html file, nothing else.*" - seriously? Would *you* believe that assurance? Regardless, post your relevant code *here*, or your question will be closed as off-topic, since we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: next time you have a question, post the code. with the internet the way it is today, that zip file could contain anything and it is not touching my hard drive. posting 5 lines of code likely took less effort than uploading and linking the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: Add a "status" variable like `var widget_is_open = false`. Upon opening the widget just use `widget_is_open = !widget_is_open;` and adjust the text accordingly - depending on the value of the variable.

In order to assign a message dynamically refer to the docs:

```
<script>
  var widget_is_open = true;
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".latestnews").click(function(){
        widget_is_open = !widget_is_open;
        $(".latestnews_toggle").toggle(1000);
     });
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rgttool').tinytooltip({
       message: function(tip) {
          if(widget_is_open===true) {return "click to close";}
          return "click to open";
        }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion can you give the complete script. I am not much so strong in javascript. Please...

Comment: answer edited with a code snippet (it is not tested)

Comment: Hi i just tested but anyhow it's not working well. please help.

Comment: edited again now with the full JS code which works. You should have now multiple `<script>`-tags in your head for including the JS-Files like JQuery and one `<script>`-tag in your body.

Comment: Hi. Many many thanks to you. Awesome. Your code worked great. I wish u will be better everyday.

Comment: @user2422363 ... someone solved your problem for you, are you now going to upvote and accept this answer?

Comment: @Stephen: he can't ([yet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)) up-vote, but acceptance is possible *if he wants to* and if this answer *fully solved the problem*. It's neither compulsory, nor obligatory to accept an answer.